# AngularDart build version in files in HTML preventing caching new build

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to achieve build solution, where I would get (after `webdev build`) files with cache-resistant urls of files, e.g. in `index.html` there would be instead of `<script defer src="main.dart.js"></script>` something like `<script defer src="main.dart.js?v=1.1.0"></script>` – I don't really care if that is the version of the package version or some random hash.

My point of this is that if I do build a new version, I need users to get this newest version, not a cached one from before (because of the same url).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a little builder that I use for this on my projects, I just published it on pub as `built_html`, see here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_html.

Let me know if it works for you and file bug reports if you find anything or want new features!

Comment: Hey, this seems to work, perfect, thanks! I will review your repository and send some PR or issues if needed. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this package. I was also looking for such a thing. Great work :)

Comment: That works fine. I just faced an issue because I copied pasted from the doc : `<script src="main.dart.js?q={{version}}"></script>` and the keyword "defer" isn't present. I need this : `<script defer src="main.dart.js?q={{version}}"></script>`